# What programming language is this in?

Tags: proxy, tabs, cross-browser

I got a script from a client, and I need to figure out exactly what's going on. What language is this written in. All I know is that it opens tabs at random intervals from a proxy list. If it's possible, could you explain what is going on? Thank you!

```
CLEAR
CMDLINE !DATASOURCE C:\temp\var2.txt
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1
SET !VAR2 {{!COL1}}
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO    
SET !DATASOURCE C:\temp\proxy.csv
'PROMPT "UserLine" !VAR2 
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!VAR2}}
'SET !LOOP 1 
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 40
SET !LOOP {{!loop}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*15 + 1); randomNumber;")
TAB T=1
PROXY ADDRESS="{{!col1}}"
'***********************************************************Resveratrol*******************************************************

URL GOTO=http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=me%3DA196A8GC0YNHR&field-keywords=resveratrol+bri
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
URL GOTO=http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=me%3DA196A8GC0YNHR&field-keywords=resveratrol+bri+nutrition
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
URL GOTO=http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=me%3DA196A8GC0YNHR&field-keywords=resveratrol+brinutrition
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like iMacros.

[blogspot](http://imacroscripts.blogspot.com.br/)

[imacros](http://wiki.imacros.net/!DATASOURCE)